# Move Android.Xamarin project from local mchine to Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, xamarin.android

I have a project that i've been working on since last year. I am using Visual Studio as my IDE for developing this project. It is a Xamarin.Android project.

Since my project is becoming really big and my local machine is not that powerful, I created  a Microsoft Azure account and want to continue the developing process using a VM. I have created the Visual Studio VM inside Microsoft Azure, and now I want to bring my source code of the project to that VM

Can anyone help with how to do this, please?

Comment: If you can log on to that VM via RDP, then you can copy files over. That’s more about how to use RDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. So for everyone that havve this question, here is a usefull resource : http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2015/03/10/copy-files-from-you-local-computer-to-an-azure-vm.aspx